# Set permissions for Git repo on Codeplex?

Tags: git, permissions, codeplex

This may be a beginner's question, but is there a way to set up permissions for Git repos on Codeplex? I have a few that are public but I'm not sure if they restrict pushes by default or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
When compared with other [open-source hosting platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_software_hosting_facilities), CodePlex:

- has no private repos (see [suggestion 26171](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/26171))
- has no private branches
- no team-only or private wiki pages (see [suggestion 25578](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/25578))